# I can not understand the extrinsic and intrinsic rotation order for `scipy` lib

Tags: scipy, computer-vision, euler-angles

After some research, for now, I understand `scipy` has right-handed axis coordinate system, and left-handed rotation.

For example

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
np.array([0,1,0]) @ R.from_euler("XYZ", [0,0,30], degrees=True).as_matrix()  # should be [0.5,sqrt(3)/2,0]
```

But I can not figure out the different between `extrinsic` and `intrinsic` rotation.

For my understanding.

`extrinsic` should use a fixed axis, and `intrinsic` should use rotatable axis.

So, if I understand this correctly.

Here "XYZ" means `intrinsic rotation`, you can find it at the [official doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html#reaa093f6923f-1)

```py
# should be [-0.5,sqrt(3)/2,-1]
# But it is [0.5,sqrt(3)/2,-1], seems like the `extrinsic rotation`
np.array([0,1,1]) @ R.from_euler("YZX", [180,30,0], degrees=True).as_matrix()
# should be [0.5,sqrt(3)/2,-1]
# But it is [-0.5,sqrt(3)/2,-1], seems like the `intrinsic rotation`
np.array([0,1,1]) @ R.from_euler("yzx", [180,30,0], degrees=True).as_matrix()
```

Am I misunderstand this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is a stupid question.

My fault.

It should multiply rotation at left.

```py
R.from_euler("YZX", [180,30,0], degrees=True).as_matrix() @ np.array([0,1,1])
```

Comment: You can also multiply at right as in the OP. Just multiply with the transpose of the transformation matrix instead.